# Can Gradle print out toal amount of tests before executing them?

Tags: gradle

In my project I have thousands of integration tests. They take lot of time to complete.

The problem is that I do not remember what amount of tests I have and therefore, during `test` task execution I have no clue what the progress is.

Is there a way for Gradle to print out `1234 of 4567 tests completed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to know the total amount of tests up front. Perhaps you could take a look through [Test.java](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/testing-jvm/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.java) to see if there's a way to hook in.

You could print out the total number of tests executed via a [TestListener](https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestListener.html) or via [Test.afterTest(Closure)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html#afterTest%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)

eg:

```
test {
    def allCount = new AtomicLong()
    def failCount = new AtomicLong()
    def skipCount = new AtomicLong()
    def successCount = new AtomicLong()
    afterTest {  TestDescriptor td, TestResult tr ->
        allCount.incrementAndGet()
        switch (tr.resultType) {
            case TestResult.FAILURE : failCount.incrementAndGet(); break;
            case TestResult.SKIPPED: skipCount.incrementAndGet(); break;
            case TestResult.SUCCESS: successCount.incrementAndGet(); break;
        }
        logger.lifecycle("All: $allCount, Success: $successCount, Fail: $failCount, Skipped: $skipCount")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Test class reference, will take a look into that.

Comment: Sorry, but that solution track numbers but only after execution of some method. It does not provide total amount of tests to be executed ("of N")

Comment: As I said "I don't think there's a way to know the total amount of tests up front. Perhaps you could take a look through Test.java to see if there's a way to hook in."